# Logstash HTTP Output Plugin Error Could not fetch URL, Network is unreachable (connect failed)

Tags: logstash, elk

I have configured a couple of pipelines in logstash, In one of the pipeline I have configured an http out plugin like

```
output {
  http {
    url => "url"
    http_method => "post"
    request_timeout => <timeout>
    automatic_retries => <retry count>
    retry_failed => false
  }
}
```

For testing purpose, I configured a webhook url in url section and checked that it is receiving GET/POST requests using curl. But when logstash try to post data on the url using logstash.outputs.http plugin, it fails with   `::Manticore::SocketException`,

**Detailed Error:**

[HTTP Output Failure] Could not fetch URL {:url=>"url", :method=>:post, :body=> "some-body" :message=>"Network is unreachable (connect failed)", :class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/manticore-0.7.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:37:in `block in initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/manticore-0.7.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:79:in` call'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-http-5.2.4/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb:239:in `send_event'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-http-5.2.4/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb:175:in` send_events'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-http-5.2.4/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb:124:in `multi_receive'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputStrategyExt.java:138:in` multi_receive'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.java:121:in `multi_receive'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:293:in` block in start_workers'"], :will_retry=>true}

Comment: Did you verify network connectivity towards the url?
If you have multiple interfaces on your logstash host it might be that you need to define a route to make sure it is going out over the correct interface.

Comment: @YouryDW How do I access this route configuration, I have deployed the logstash on a kubernetes cluster.

Comment: I do not have enough experience with Kubernetes to be able to answer your question on this, I would start looking into this page: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/